# Alter CSS keyframe to reveal horizontally from the middle instead of vertically

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to alter this CSS animation to work on vh instead of width %. Basically I need it to reveal horizontally from the middle up and down instead of to the left and right.

[Click here to see the vertical example](http://codepen.io/zubfatal/pen/eZZerN)

Attempted many different things to decipher a solution, but doing the following (see below) does not do anything.

```
@keyframes curtain
0%, 50%
    height: 50vh
100%
    width: 0
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600);
 body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
#intro {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#intro::before,
#intro::after {
  -webkit-animation: curtain 2s;
  -moz-animation: curtain 2s;
  -o-animation: curtain 2s;
  animation: curtain 2s;
  background-color: #152a33;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
#intro::before {
  left: 0;
}
#intro::after {
  right: 0;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.table .cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
@-webkit-keyframes curtain {
  0%, 50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes curtain {
  0%, 50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes curtain {
  0%, 50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes curtain {
  0%, 50% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="intro">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, beatae eius veritatis voluptate ab minus deserunt aliquam saepe, error maiores pariatur nam illo natus dolorem veniam, doloremque, expedita officiis esse.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, natus? Non aperiam eaque neque vero perspiciatis, reprehenderit eveniet quae ut omnis voluptatem architecto maxime cum quaerat dignissimos porro. Provident, magnam!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Anybody please got a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the positioning attributes, `height` and `width` of the pseudo-elements both in the normal state and within the keyframes. You seem to have done only the change within the keyframes and so it hadn't worked properly.

In the original demo, both the pseudo-elements have `bottom: 0` and `top: 0` which means it gets the full height of the parent (`100vh`). The `:before` is positioned with respect to the left edge of the parent whereas the `:after` is positioned with respect to right edge. During the animation both get `50%` width and thus produce the curtain move effect towards left and right.

For the curtain move effect towards top and bottom, the pseudo-elements need to take `100%` width of their parent and be positioned with respect to the top and bottom edges respectively (`left:0` can be applied for both because both should be positioned at left-top and left-bottom respectively).

```css
&::before, &::after
    animation: curtain 2s
    background-color: #152a33
    content: ''
    left: 0
    position: absolute

&::before
    top: 0
    width: 100%

&::after
    bottom: 0
    width: 100%
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600);
 body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
#intro {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#intro::before,
#intro::after {
  -webkit-animation: curtain 2s;
  -moz-animation: curtain 2s;
  -o-animation: curtain 2s;
  animation: curtain 2s;
  background-color: #152a33;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#intro::before {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#intro::after {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.table .cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
@-webkit-keyframes curtain {
  0%, 50% {
    height: 50vh;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes curtain {
  0%, 50% {
    height: 50vh;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes curtain {
  0%, 50% {
    height: 50vh;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes curtain {
  0%, 50% {
    height: 50vh;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="intro">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, beatae eius veritatis voluptate ab minus deserunt aliquam saepe, error maiores pariatur nam illo natus dolorem veniam, doloremque, expedita officiis esse.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, natus? Non aperiam eaque neque vero perspiciatis, reprehenderit eveniet quae ut omnis voluptatem architecto maxime cum quaerat dignissimos porro. Provident, magnam!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

It was about top and bottom at before and after pseudo-elements because you gave from the start full height . If you change your code to this :

```
&::before, &::after
    -webkit-animation: curtain 2s
    -moz-animation: curtain 2s
    -o-animation: curtain 2s
    animation: curtain 2s
    background-color: #152a33
    right: 0 <!-- The change -->
    content: ''
    position: absolute
    left: 0 <!-- The change -->
```

Also change right and left with top and bottom :

```
&::before
    top: 0

&::after
    bottom: 0
```

and finally change in keyframes the width with height you will see the result you want :

@keyframes curtain
    0%, 50%
        height: 50%
    100%
        height: 0

So the full code would be like this :

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600);
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
}

#intro {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1170px;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#intro::before, #intro::after {
  -webkit-animation: curtain 2s;
  -moz-animation: curtain 2s;
  -o-animation: curtain 2s;
  animation: curtain 2s;
  background-color: #152a33;
  right: 0;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
#intro::before {
  top: 0;
}
#intro::after {
  bottom: 0;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.table .cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@-webkit-keyframes curtain {
  0%, 50% {
    height: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes curtain {
  0%, 50% {
    height: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes curtain {
  0%, 50% {
    height: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes curtain {
  0%, 50% {
    height: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="intro">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, beatae eius veritatis voluptate ab minus deserunt aliquam saepe, error maiores pariatur nam illo natus dolorem veniam, doloremque, expedita officiis esse.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt, natus? Non aperiam eaque neque vero perspiciatis, reprehenderit eveniet quae ut omnis voluptatem architecto maxime cum quaerat dignissimos porro. Provident, magnam!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```